# Makes index.html part of the path

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, servlets

I am building a web game, also using Java servlets - running it locally with TomCat.
The main page url is: `localhost:8080/index.html/`

Whenever I try to move to other servlet\page the path is: `localhost:8080/index.html/inGame.html`
as if `index.html` is a folder.

How can I fix it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: somehow you have set root url of your folder to '/index.html' set it to '/' instead.... and better replace index.html from request url to '/' so that both www.domain.com/ and www.domain.com/index.html works

Comment: i'm quite a beginner, so can you give me a hint where do I do it? :)

Comment: please paste some of your code so that I can help you out it should be something like if(request.getRequestURI().equals("/some/path")){
            request.getRequestDispatcher("/path/where/servlet/registered").forward(request, response);
            return; // prevents normal request processing

        } or you may have that configuration in web.xml

Comment: @GilBrud Is your project name index.html.To to start an application generally we do http://localhost:8080/project_name but in your case its localhost:8080/index.html

Comment: @javaBeginner no, the name of the project is TicTacToe

as i understand in the web.xml it suppose to be the /index.html as the path.

Comment: @GilBrud show your web.xml and also show your project structure

Comment: The main page url is **NOT** `localhost:8080/index.html/`. The main page is `localhost:8080/index.html` without a slash!

Answer (score 0):

i think your code should be like this

RequestDispatcher a = request.getRequestDispatcher("other servlet url/ mapping");

a.forward(request, response);